# regex that doesn't match between HTML comments

Tags: regex

I have a regex that I want to match a certain pattern. However, I don't want it to match that pattern if it exists between HTML comment blocks

What I have currently is:

```
(?<!<!--)pattern(?!-->)
```

However that only works when the pattern is exactly between comment blocks but not in the case of something like:

```
<!-- foo pattern -->
```

But if I do:

```
(?<!<!--.*)pattern(?!-->)
```

then this case doesn't work:

```
<!-- some commented out stuff --> pattern
```

I think if I could express (everything except -->)*? within the negative look behind it would work but I'm unsure of the proper syntax or if that's allowed.

Comment: `(?<!<!--[^<>]*)pattern(?![^<>]*-->)` might work then. What you ask for is ``(?<!(?:(?!<!--|-->).)*)pattern(?!(?:(?!<!--|-->).)*-->)``

Comment: Use a real HTML parser. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: When you say `between comment blocks`, if you have 400 comment blocks or 2, all it takes is to have a comment block at the top, and one at the bottom.

Comment: No matter how you try, there is only one way to do this, replace  the first and last comment, and everything between with nothing, then try a new regex with your pattern on what's left.

Comment: You can't just say `(?:<!--comment-->.*<!--comment-->)?.*?pattern` it finds pattern no matter what. You could match both, to move past comments like this `(?:<!--comment-->.*<!--comment-->)|(pattern)` then see if group 1 matched. It's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that, your original expression is just fine with maybe a bit modification, we might want to have an expression similar to:

```
(?<=<!--).*pattern.*(?=-->)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P4aHyw/1/)

and if we wish to capture or not-capture anything around `pattern` these might be of interest:

```
(?<=<!--).*(pattern).*(?=-->)
(?<=<!--)(.*pattern.*)(?=-->)
(?<=<!--)(.*)(pattern)(.*)(?=-->)
(?<=<!--)(?:.*)(pattern)(?:.*)(?=-->)
```